# To print string which has max length in Python Dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, string-length

I have a dataframe in which I found the way to print the longest and smallest length of object in each column, but I want to print the string also instead of printing just a length.

Comment: You shold give more informations about your dataframe and your code and what you expect to code do.

Comment: @SMortezaSA this is my code, i just want to print max,min record of each column. df=pd.read_csv(P1-UK-Bank-Customers.csv") for col in df.select_dtypes([np.int8, np.int16, np.int32, np.int64, np.float]): print('max: ',df[col].max()) print('min: ',df[col].min()) i did for int,float, need solution for object? And in object's case I need to print the data based on the length.

Answer (score 3):

If this is your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['abc','de','hijkl']})
print(df)
       A
0    abc
1     de
2  hijkl


max_len = df[df['A'].str.len() == df['A'].str.len().max()]

print(max_len)
       A
2  hijkl
```

or a general, and much simplier solution using pure python suggested by @Błotosmętek

```
max_len = max(df['A'], key=len)

print(max_len)


'hijkl'
```

Comment: Or simpler: `max_len = max(df['A'], key=len)`

Comment: @Błotosmętek nice one - I'll add it to my post

Comment: Just my two cents. While the non-pandas answers can seem simpler/faster they easily break with missing data or when applied on `object` columns that might not be solely string data.I find it a wash at that point, unless you're certain your data are perfectly clean and without issue. Still always good to have a faster solution when permitting :D

Comment: @Datanovice  this is my code, i just want to print max,min record of each column.                                        
   df=pd.read_csv(P1-UK-Bank-Customers.csv")                                   
    for col in df.select_dtypes([np.int8, np.int16, np.int32, np.int64, np.float]):          
    print('max: ',df[col].max())      
    print('min: ',df[col].min())    
i did for int,float, need solution for object?

Comment: @Datanovice  for col in df.iterows:  
    if df[col].dtype == 'object':  
        print('min length of column %s: %s\n' %  (col, [df[col].map(len).min()]))  this prints min len of object.

Comment: @pooja provide a sample of your dataframe and i'll adapt my answer

Comment: Customer ID Name Surname Gender Age Region 
0 100000001 Simon Walsh Male 21 England  
1 400000002 Jasmine Miller Female 34 Northern Ireland @Datanovice     This is the sample data and im giving txt/csv file which reads and forms dataframe, so the logic should work for any file which i give..  pls give a solution?

Comment: @Datanovice  Customer ID Name Surname Gender Age Region 0 100000001 Simon Walsh Male 21 England 1 400000002 Jasmine Miller Female 34 Northern Ireland This is the sample data and im giving txt/csv file which reads and forms dataframe, so the logic should work for any file which i give.. pls give a solution?

Comment: Can you add it to your main post?